# Codeigniter to Laravel decoding

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, encryption, encode

I have an app in codeigniter that i am migrating to laravel

The code in codeigniter checks a password using this codeigniter library

$CI->encrypt->decode(password,key)

What would the code be to do this in laravel?

UPDATE
The password was being decrypted using CodeIgniter with a given key

I am trying to find the translated code to do this in Laravel given the existing passwords in the DB

Comment: What is CodeIgniter and PHP version?

Comment: @MDutt CI 2.12 LARAVEL 5.5

Comment: Found CI 2.2.6 user guide link https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/encryption.html and Mcrypt link https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: @MDutt

Thank you, I found those references. CI encryption class automatically got iv from encrypted value. Trying to figure out how to get iv to pass into mcrypt_decrypt on laravel end

Comment: _Application\Libraries\Auth.php_ OR _System\Libraries\Encript.php_ may help you in finding the solution.

Comment: @MDutt Libraries/Encrypt.php has the decode function used in CI. Would i have to migrate this manually to laravel?

Comment: Check what decode function is returning. Based on data take a call, if it is plain text then in a loop you can use Laravel's Hash facade (it uses bcrypt) to encrypt and store. So that Laravel's default Auth has no issue. Or override Laravel's Auth to work with CI's decode. Between the two bcrypt is more secure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211167/discussion-between-peter-and-m-dutt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate the necessary functions in CI library(System\Libraries\Encrypt.php) being used to Laravel.